# searching for a user with mongodb, mongoose

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to include functionality for users to search my app for other users.

I have an input field in my navbar form:

```
form.form-inline
   .input-group
      input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Search for a user', name='search', aria-label='Search')
           .input-group-append
               button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit')
```

Then, in my router file, I have this post route:

```
// post route for searching for a user
router.post('/feed', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    var name = req.body.search;
    var regex = new RegExp(name, 'i');

    User.find({'$or': [{'firstname': regex}, {'username': regex}]}, (err, foundUser) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          res.send("Found user is " + foundUser)
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, the post is not working correctly and I'm not sure what's wrong. Typing something into the search bar gives me a url string of something like this : http://localhost:3000/users/feed?search=tilda

but nothing is being sent and I'm not sure the post route is even hitting my db.

Comment: don't you think the route should be a get method and not post?

Comment: I have a get above it that renders the page. Since the user is inputting the search field into an input box and passing that info to the db, shouldn't it be a post?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up query string parameters with POST parameters.

`http://localhost:3000/users/feed?search=tilda` is a query string parameter.  You have to get that out of the request object with

`const { query: { search } } = req;`

If you are posting data in the body, you use the code that you have written with

`const { search } = req.body;`

For you're use case of searching for a name, you should use GET and query parameters to be restful.

Edited to reflect suggestion by @Neil Lunn

Comment: Or just `const { query: { search } } = req` since you can simply do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/feed', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    var name = req.query.search;
    var searchItem = '/'+name+'/' // basically checking for %Joh%

    User.find({'$or': [{'firstname': searchItem}, {'username': searchItem}]}, (err, foundUser) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          res.send("Found user is " + foundUser)
        }
    });
});
```

Please do make sure your isLoggedIn middleware returns true/ calls next() in order to pass the req/res object inside your router handling function.